# Scrollbar hidden under absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

Im trying to achieve a content div with a sticky header without using sticky. My approach generally works fine expect for the part where the absolutely positioned element hides the scrollbar of the content.

Is there any way to have the content still under the absolutely positioned element but the scrollbar on top?

### HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

        <div class="contentBar">
        </div>

        <div class="contentscroll">
            <span id="clickable">
                Clickable text
            </span>

            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

/*  */
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

/* SIDEMENU RELATED */

.menu{
    width:200px;
    /* left:20px; */
    background-color:rgb(197, 228, 201);
}

.menuClosed{
    width:0px;
    background-color:rgb(197, 228, 201);
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

/* CONTENT RELATED */

.content{
    background-color:rgb(236, 167, 110);
    flex:1;
    position:relative;
}

.contentscroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    height:100%;
}

.contentBar{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.contentitem{
    height:400px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:rgb(206, 103, 19)
}
```

### jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/suvetoduqu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is add a fake content bar taking same space as content bar. Look at the scroll problem which is fixed.

Added `<div class="contentBarfake"></div>` in html and `.contentBarFake` in style.

```css
.html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

/*  */
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

/* SIDEMENU RELATED */

.menu{
    width:200px;
    /* left:20px; */
    background-color:rgb(197, 228, 201);
}

.menuClosed{
    width:0px;
    background-color:rgb(197, 228, 201);
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

/* CONTENT RELATED */

.content{
    background-color:rgb(236, 167, 110);
    flex:1;
    position:relative;
}

.contentscroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    height:100%;
}

.contentBar{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.contentBarfake{
  position:relative;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:200px;
}
.contentitem{
    height:400px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:rgb(206, 103, 19)
}

@media (max-width: 500px){

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div>Item 1</div>
        <div>Item 2</div>
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

        <div class="contentBar">
        </div>
      <div class="contentBarfake">
        </div>

        <div class="contentscroll">
            <span id="clickable">
                Clickable text
            </span>

            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
            <div class="contentitem">
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
```